# How to point quartz to spring hikariCP datasource?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, hikaricp

my application is setting a simple data source via properties

```
spring.datasource.username=${database.username}
spring.datasource.password=${database.password}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${database.host}/databasename
```

which gets picked up by hikari autoconfig.

But then fail to be seen be quartz autoconfig when using `LocalDataSourceJobStore`

```
<bean id="QuartzClusteredScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="????"/> -->
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="com.example.scheduler.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore</prop>
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>...
```

What is the correct way to point quartz to the hikariCP pool?

If I ommit the dataSource attributed, like I the manual for spring's quartz autoconfigure suggests, I get
`java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'null'`
If i put any other name and use `spring.datasource.name=abc` then i get that it can't find `abc` or `jdbc/abc` just the same.

I'm trying to understand the discussion on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28758 which seems to be what is affecting me, but everything is mentioned so lightly i am not sure how to follow.

Comment: Have you tried <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the datasource name in your application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.mysql.username=${database.username}
spring.datasource.mysql.password=${database.password}
spring.datasource.mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://${database.host}/databasename
```

then in your bean difinition,  you can try ref this datasource.

I just found an example at: http://www.masterspringboot.com/programming/various/getting-started-with-quartz-and-spring-boot/
Maybe you can try the code from very beginning.

Comment: How can I "ref this datasource"?

Comment: By default,  it will ref the bean of "DataSource".  Need not specify anything.

Comment: i might have something wrong on this old project. because i get `java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'null'` if I don't pass any.